# Is it possible there are Bluetooth devices connected which do not appear in the Bluetooth settings?

Tags: bluetooth

We have a Bluetooth sensor which is mounted to the windscreen of the car. It uses Bluetooth to connect to a smartphone. The sensor records driving behavior and we get a discount on the insurance if we drive well.

But the smartphone app doesn't record anything so I wanted to check if the sensor is connected properly. But the sensor doesn't appear in the Android Bluetooth settings. Not as paired device and also not as available device.

The insurance company claims at their website that it's normal that the sensor does not appear in the Android Bluetooth settings.

Is it possible that a Bluetooth device communicates with the smartphone even if it's not listed in the Android Bluetooth settings?

Comment: You can activate developer options on your device and then activate the "Bluetooth HCI snoop log". If the app then directly communicates with the device without pairing/bonding then it should still be visible in the snoop log. While having that option enabled I would not use any other Bluetooth devices.